# Reproducing kernel Hilbert space of functions which vanish at a point

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, statistics

I need help finding the kernel function for a particular subspace of a reproducing kernel Hilbert space.

Let $\cal{H}$ be an RKHS on $X$ with reproducing kernel $K$, fix $x_0 \in X$ and let $\cal{H}_0 = \{f \in \cal{H} : f(x_0)=0\}$. What would be the kernel function for $\cal{H}_0$?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $H_0$, then $$K_0(x,y)=\langle Pk_y,k_x\rangle$$ is the kernel for any closed subspace $H_0$. Here, $k_x$ is the unique element of $H$ such that $\langle f,k_x\rangle=f(x)$ for all $f\in H$.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that fact. How does this apply to the problem at hand?